# fputcsv and issue with bigint in excel

Tags: php, csv

I'm exporting data in csv it's ok but when i open it in excel the field with the bigint (14 digit).

It come strange but if i click in cell on excel it show the original value.

I tried many thing to fix it like using strval in this value before using fputcsv to create csv but no 1 them worked.

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that Excel interprets those values in a wrong way? Try manually adding `'` in front of one wrongly displayed cell value in Excel. Does it show up correct afterward?

Comment: i tried it, it works but it show ' in excel

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your export in php. If you see number like 3.453454+17 just format your cell as text.

Excel by default shows only 11 digits and bigger number such as credit card number are converted to float representation.

Comment: Like I said. In excel use format to change the view: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2643223